# show a notification instead of the error message log of magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I used a cart observed to block 1 single item in the cart and then display a notification to the user like a notification style "you coold select just one item"  the problem that it's appears to me the error log magento first then when I return to the home page. I find my message displayed. I just want to display it in my page and not also in the error log page.

config.xml

```
        <events>
            <catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
                <observers>
                    <Amir_Prince_observer>
                        <class>Amir_Prince/ObserverCountItemCart</class>
                        <method>limiter_panier</method>
                    </Amir_Prince_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
        </events>
```

My Observer:

```
class Amir_Prince_Model_ObserverCountItemCart{
    public function limiter_panier(Varient_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $quote = $session->getQuote();

    if($quote->getItemsCount()>=1){
    $message = 'You can select only one item.';
    $session->addError($message); 
    // Mage::thrownewException($message); // the log error commented
    throw new Exception($message);// the frontend notification

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: what event are you using?

Comment: my event: catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options

Comment: where is that event dispatched? I cannot find the `Mage::dispatchEvent()` call in the code.

Comment: what event you want to say, in the config.xml ? look I post you what I have done in my question on the top

Comment: Not your code...I wanted to know the core file where this event is dispatched. To get and idea what happens before or after your observer is called.

Comment: Excuse me Marius, but I can't get know exactly which file you need. I create a custom module and I put my observer inside in a Model.
My path is: index.phtml ->result.phtml-> cart.phtml->checkout,
in result.phtml i do the action of (add to cart)

Comment: if the cart contains '0 item' he add the item to the cart with no problem .its good but if the cart already contains '1 item' and the user want to add a 2nd he block the add with my observer (what i wanted) but the message i want to display it in the same page (result.phtml).  if its not possible, in the home page.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve. I just didn't find the core code that dispatches the event you are observing. but no problem. I will dig deeper and if I find something I will post an answer.

Comment: ok thank you, i remain at your disposal if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `throw new Exception($message);` you can try this:

```
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$refererUrl = $request->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
if ($url = $request->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL)) {
    $refererUrl = $url;
}
if ($url = $request->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL)) {
    $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
}
if ($url = $request->getParam(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
    $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
}
$refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->escapeUrl($refererUrl);
if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($refererUrl)) {
    $refererUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
}
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
exit;
```

this will redirect to the previous page and you will see the notice above the page.

**[EDIT]**
and add this method in your observer

```
protected function _isUrlInternal($url)
{
    if (strpos($url, 'http') !== false) {
        /**
         * Url must start from base secure or base unsecure url
         */
        if ((strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl()) === 0)
            || (strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, true)) === 0)
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i tried it and look the result: 
(364 Fatal error) at this line : if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($refererUrl))

Comment: Sorry. I forgot a method. See my update.

Comment: should i put some url in the mathod in the commented part: /*Url must start from base secure or base unsecure url*/
this time i havn't an error against but a blank page. I wonder if it's my page that contains an error or in the observ. your code it refreshed me well result.phtml page but no content. I try to go from result.phtml to cart and returned backwards or just refresh the page, and it shows me although my content. !

Comment: I verified my page code, there's no mistake. can we do a redirect to cart which is the next page and display the message above, otherwise if it's not possible display it in the home page.